# Access element in eventListener by element index in javascript

Tags: javascript, element, event-listener

I want to add EventListener for .author_show class to change .author 
styles... this is my code

```
<div class="post>
    <div class="post-cont>
        // Some text
        <div class="author_show"></div>
        <div class="author_show"></div>
        // Some text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="authors">
    <div class="author"></div>
    <div class="author"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var author_show = document.getElementsByClassName("author_show");
var authors = document.getElementsByClassName("author");
for(var i=0;i<authors.length;i++)
{
    author_show[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
        authors[i].style.display = "block"; // Problem
    })
}
</script>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a `scope` per iteration,

```
for(var i=0; i<authors.length; i++) {
   (function(i) {
      author_show[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
        authors[i].style.display = "block"; // Problem
      }); 
    })(i);
}
```

In your code the addEventListener will not cause any problem. But the style setting block will rely on an `i` that belongs to a single scope. As for loop iterates that `i` will be incremented and the final value of `i` will be reflected inside of all the events. So you have to create a scope per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're going for :

```js
var author_show = document.getElementsByClassName("author_show");
var authors = document.getElementsByClassName("author");

for(var i=0;i<authors.length;i++) {
    (function(i) {
        var author = author_show[i];
        var style = authors[i].style;
        author.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            style.display = "block"; // Problem
        });
        author.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
            style.display = "none"; // Problem
        });
    })(i);
}
```

```css
.author {
   display : none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-cont">
        // Some text
        <div class="author_show">Show A</div>
        <div class="author_show">Show B</div>
        // Some text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="authors">
    <div class="author">Author A</div>
    <div class="author">Author B</div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh4g1L4k/5/))